# Blocked by CORS policy in React JS

Tags: reactjs, powerbi-embedded, msal-react

I'm having difficulty developing a readjs script. I created the application at Microsoft and access via Postman is working. When I implement it in react, it returns the error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/******/oauth2/v2.0/token' from
> origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No '
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource

[image]

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { PowerBIEmbed } from 'powerbi-client-react';
import { models } from 'powerbi-client';
import axios from 'axios';


function App() {

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        'https://login.microsoftonline.com/f47178f*****/oauth2/v2.0/token',
        'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=*****ec97be119&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret=*****~lpwFCZ_Vfv4Mu2QvhW43rz.auh',
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          },
        }
      );
      console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  };

  fetchData();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <PowerBIEmbed
          embedConfig={{
            type: 'report',   // Supported types: report, dashboard, tile, visual and qna
            id: 'd3229ac5-5501-42db-b45b-dcd76473161b',
            embedUrl: "",
            accessToken: "",
            tokenType: models.TokenType.Aad,
            settings: {
              panes: {
                filters: {
                  expanded: false,
                  visible: true
                }
              },
            }
          }}

          eventHandlers={
            new Map([
              ['loaded', function () { console.log('Report loaded'); }],
              ['rendered', function () { console.log('Report rendered'); }],
              ['error', function (event) { console.log(event.detail); }]
            ])
          }

          cssClassName={"Embed-container"}

          getEmbeddedComponent={(embeddedReport) => {
            window.report = embeddedReport;
          }}
        />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This call has to be made server-side; it cannot be made via client-side requests. Your client secret is poorly censored and you should regenerate it for safety.

Comment: You should delete this question if you put secrets in here.  Edit history is visible to anyone

Comment: calling `fetchData();` as you do will recall it each time App re-renders

Comment: The secrets are hidden

Comment: @EduardoSantos The secrets are poorly hidden in your screenshot; a dedicated person could probably figure them out. They are not at all hidden in your React code; anyone can open up the developer tools and see the call to `login.microsoftonline.com` and get the client secret out of it. At that point, your app is compromised. There are no CORS headers on that endpoint because **it should never be called like this**.

Answer (score -1):

Refer to [React Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/React-TS) if you're Embedding report for organization.

If you're Embedding report using Service principal,  Refer to my [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/KotanaSai21/powerbi-embedded-React-demo).

Need to provide more details on the way you're embedding and which authentication method you're using to get appropriate answer for the issue facing.